# PowerShell Write to Same File Multiple Jobs

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I have a script that pulls one line of data from a file on multiple servers. I have a single-threaded version that works just fine, but I want to get it to run faster. Since I only need one line of one file from each server, I'm sure I could run this in parallel. I pulled code from multiple places to get a multi-threaded script running, but when I try to get all the results to print to one output file, nothing prints. I wonder if anyone can look at my code to tell me why this same script, without the Jobs, works fine, but after adding jobs, it doesn't.

```
$sb =  {
   Param($computer, $fileName, $outLog)
   net use "\\$computer\c$" **** /user:****
   if(test-path \\$computer\c$\sc\$fileName){
      [xml]$periods = Get-Content \\$computer\c$\sc\$fileName
      $endDate = $periods.PeriodDetail | select -last 1
      $output = "$computer;$endDate"
   }
   Else {
      $output = "$computer;$fileName Not Found"
   }
   #Synchronize file usage
   $mutex = new-object System.Threading.Mutex $false,'SomeUniqueName'
   $mutex.WaitOne() > $null
   #Write data to log
   Out-File -Append -InputObject $output -FilePath $outLog
   #Release file hold
   $mutex.ReleaseMutex()

   net use "\\$computer\c$" /de 
}

foreach($computer in $computerName){
   while ((Get-Job -State Running).Count -ge 20) {
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
   }
   Start-Job -Scriptblock $sb -ArgumentList $computer,$fileName,$outLog
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Proper parallel data processing in PowerShell is tricky. There are ready solutions.
Take a look at the module [SplitPipeline](https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline).
Your task is reduced to the code like `$computerName | Split-Pipeline -Count 20
{process{ operate of each $_, output data normally }} | Out-File ...`.

Comment: Why not let the scriptblock `Write-Output` the result and then just pipe the `Receive-Job` output (which would the be output strings) to the `Out-File` cmdlet? Then you wouldn't have to try to work with the `Mutex` class unnecessarily.

Comment: @robert: because I had no idea how I wanted to to that, or what was even possible. I will try that.

Comment: Great! Let us know how it went.

Comment: It works great, except it prints out the lines about net use connecting and disconnecting. I could possibly write-error or something similar I'm guessing? Otherwise I can scrub those out of the output if nothing else.

Comment: @joshua re: net use lines. pipe them to `out-null`, ie.  `net use... | out-null` and you won't see any output from the command

Comment: @robert: Since you answered almost every one of my questions perfectly, why not create an answer? I can answer my own question with what you gave me, but that hardly seems fair.

Comment: @JoshuaNurczyk If you're still having problems with this I'd love to write up a sample for you, but if you have already solved it it's better if you write the answer yourself. Are you still having problems or have you solved your problem?

Comment: I solved it, with your help. I'll write up the answer. Just wanted to give credit where it is due.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for all the assistance. Here is the resulting code that works pretty well:

```
$sb =  {
   Param($computer, $fileName, $outLog)
   net use "\\$computer\c$" $password /user:$userName | Out-Null
   if(test-path \\$computer\c$\sc\$fileName){
      [xml]$periods = Get-Content \\$computer\c$\sc\$fileName
      $endDate = $periods.IndataDbf.ingredient.PeriodDetail.PeriodEndDate | select -last 1
         $output = "$computer;$endDate"
      }
   Else {
      $output = "$computer;$fileName Not Found"
   }
   Write-Output -InputObject $output
   net use "\\$computer\c$" /de | Out-Null
}

foreach($computer in $computerName){
   while ((Get-Job -State Running).Count -ge 20) {
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
   }
   Start-Job -Scriptblock $sb -ArgumentList $computer,$fileName,$outLog
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outLog
```

I'm thinking of doing another `Get-Job` right before the `Start-Job`, getting only jobs that are complete with more data, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: "Works pretty well"? Are you having issues with the code? (By the way, you should probably accept the answer, so that others see that it has been correctly answered.)

Comment: No issues, just looking at optimizing it for memory use and the like is all. It's querying over 1000 machines, so it will hold all of the output in memory until the end.

Comment: Well, since you for some reason (good or not, I have no idea, but I guess you added all the jobs and ran into issues with it) start the jobs in batches, you could also retrieve their results when they are done. Do some `Get-Job -State Completed | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoteJob | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outLog` in your loop to get the results successively for the jobs which are completed.

Comment: I'll try adding all the jobs at once and see if it kills th machine and also try it with getting the successive output in the loop to see what is fastest.

Comment: Out of memory error when taking out the code making it into batches. Haven't had a chance to try `Get-Job` in the loop.